# How can I divide by index and add item in nested list keeping it nested?

Tags: python, list, nested

My question is, how can I divide items by index and add string specific value
in nested list.

## My list:

```
lst = [['  21693282.469 7                  -4963125.899 7  -3821950.54648  21693275.40648\n',
    '  20789781.031 7                    887006.789 7    698075.62748  20789776.77048\n',
    '  24667814.375 5  24667811.441 8   1051991.202 5    827710.336 8  24667810.98847\n',
    '  21414305.883 6  21414301.563 9  -5293000.520 6  -4102616.060 9  21414301.17248\n',
    '  23395450.500 6                   1349998.701 6   1080794.20346  23395447.42246\n',
     '  20965956.617 8                  -3636447.948 8  -2813703.22949  20965951.97349\n'],
     ['  20670086.656 7                   2718596.518 7   2116872.80448  20670081.07848\n',
     '  24222343.500 3                   2146415.760 3   1607697.95946  24222340.25446\n',
     '  22829139.453 6                   1683633.646 6   1300012.93847  22829132.80147\n',
     '  22934656.609 6                   1700166.043 6   1314411.856 7  22934663.711 7\n',
     '  20055874.828 9                    267080.471 9    212506.020 9  20055882.121 9\n',
     '  22774080.570 7                   1762178.392 7   1346501.808 8  22774088.434 8\n',
     '  20194290.688 8                  -2867460.044 8  -2213132.457 9  20194298.629 9\n',
     '  21679624.156 7                   1345827.111 7   1067174.299 8  21679631.973 8\n']]
```

## My code is here:

```
result=[] 

def extract_line():

    for list in lst:
        for j in list:
            for i in range(0,len(j)-1,16):
                num = j[i:i+16].strip()

                result.append(num if num else 'None')
    yield result

for result in extract_line():
    print result
```

I can get only one list not nested

## I want to get list keeping nested list like this:

```
[['21693282.469 7', 'None', '-4963125.899 7', '-3821950.54648', '21693275.40648',
 '20789781.031 7', 'None', '887006.789 7', '698075.62748', '20789776.77048',
 '24667814.375 5', '24667811.441 8', '1051991.202 5', '827710.336 8', '24667810.98847',
 '21414305.883 6', '21414301.563 9', '-5293000.520 6', '-4102616.060 9', '21414301.17248',
 '23395450.500 6', 'None', '1349998.701 6', '1080794.20346', '23395447.42246',
 '20965956.617 8', 'None', '-3636447.948 8', '-2813703.22949', '20965951.97349'],
 ['20670086.656 7', 'None', '2718596.518 7', '2116872.80448', '20670081.07848',
 '24222343.500 3', 'None', '2146415.760 3', '1607697.95946', '24222340.25446',
 '22829139.453 6', 'None', '1683633.646 6', '1300012.93847', '22829132.80147',
 '22934656.609 6', 'None', '1700166.043 6', '1314411.856 7', '22934663.711 7',
 ........ '21679631.973 8']]
```

## I'm so sorry

cuz I'm not habituated using this webpage yet 
 I edit my question readable easier than before

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please describe the desired result in words.

Comment: Please, provide more clear examples, because, cmon, now they are completely unreadable

Comment: It looks like you twisted my [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507313/python-how-can-i-replace-in-list-item/40509294?noredirect=1#comment68267183_40509294). `result` have to be inside `extract_line()` otherwise it is useless to `yield`. Also, it will be very nice for to accept, comment or upvote my first answer if it solved your problem. That's how stackoverflow works.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: if `myList` is the list you want to be nested, just write `myList = [myList]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, DON'T use list (which is a class) as a variable name. Python will not say anything, but it will bite you (hard) later.

(Same with dict, file, ...). When in doubt, add my_ before anything
Second, it seems you don't want to return a list of items, but a list which has a single item in it.
   The easiest solution would be not to yield result, but

```
yield [result]
```

Which would return the list you want (your list as the only element in a list)

Comment: oh Thank you I didn't know that.
I think I have to insert "if" to keeping nested format....

Answer (score 0):

Below I posted the solution. Introduce the sublist, to keep your list nesting.

```
lst = [['  21693282.469 7                  -4963125.899 7  -3821950.54648  21693275.40648\n',
    '  20789781.031 7                    887006.789 7    698075.62748  20789776.77048\n',
    '  24667814.375 5  24667811.441 8   1051991.202 5    827710.336 8  24667810.98847\n',
    '  21414305.883 6  21414301.563 9  -5293000.520 6  -4102616.060 9  21414301.17248\n',
    '  23395450.500 6                   1349998.701 6   1080794.20346  23395447.42246\n',
     '  20965956.617 8                  -3636447.948 8  -2813703.22949  20965951.97349\n'],
     ['  20670086.656 7                   2718596.518 7   2116872.80448  20670081.07848\n',
     '  24222343.500 3                   2146415.760 3   1607697.95946  24222340.25446\n',
     '  22829139.453 6                   1683633.646 6   1300012.93847  22829132.80147\n',
     '  22934656.609 6                   1700166.043 6   1314411.856 7  22934663.711 7\n',
     '  20055874.828 9                    267080.471 9    212506.020 9  20055882.121 9\n',
     '  22774080.570 7                   1762178.392 7   1346501.808 8  22774088.434 8\n',
     '  20194290.688 8                  -2867460.044 8  -2213132.457 9  20194298.629 9\n',
     '  21679624.156 7                   1345827.111 7   1067174.299 8  21679631.973 8\n']]


result=[] 

def extract_line():

    for list in lst:
    print 'list:',list
    sublist=[]
        for j in list:    
            for i in range(0,len(j)-1,16):
                num = j[i:i+16].strip()

                sublist.append(num if num else 'None')
        result.append(sublist)
    yield result

for result in extract_line():
    print '\n\n\n'
    print result
```